# First ROR controller - No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I barely got my Ruby on Rails environment working, I walked through and got my hello world app going and added another method and it gives me no route matches.

I created a controller called say_hello_controller.rb, with this code inside.

```
class SayHelloController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :text => "Hello World"
  end   

  def bye
    render :text => "bye bye"
  end 
end
```

Here is the error http://screencast.com/t/h3ke1hjg8.

The strange this is that http://localhost:3000/say_hello/index does work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your config/routes.rb doesn't have record of say_hello/bye

You would want to add:

```
 match 'say_hello/bye' => 'say_hello#bye'
```

However I suggest reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default to get a grasp on routes/resources.

Comment: Ok that is right.  It works now.  I will have to read through the guide here to understand it more.  I thought the point was to have this convention that automatically made life easier and not have to configure a bunch of stuff, putting routes in configs seems a little contrary to the ror way :)

Comment: The point is not putting routes in the configs -- the point is you're not using the standard routes. You can turn on "wildcard" routes which means every action you define will be findable, but that isn't RESTful. By default rails routes are: index, show, new, create, edit, update, and delete. Those 7 should be plenty for most things you'll do, and adding a custom route occasionally is quite easy to do.